# Merge a fix from main to branch or vice versa?

Tags: version-control, branching-and-merging, release-management

In version control, we have a main branch and recently created a release branch. We were dicussing, where to fix an issue and where to merge it (fix in main and forward integrate to release or fix in release and reverse integrate to main).

Microsoft states in their "Branching and Merging Primer" (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/vsts/repos/tfvc/branching-strategies-with-tfvc?view=vsts) that one should never forward integrate from main to release. But they don't present I reason, nor can I think of one.

Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on your particular way to use a SCM - independently of which one you use.
It makes a difference if you are a company with 1000 committers working on one single
product or if you are talking about a tiny project with just 3 people.

However in general it is indeed not a good idea to merge changes from a main line to
a release line.
Imagine your mainline frequently gets commits (either directly or merged from other branches).
Now we assume that the main branch got some bugfixes that you also want in your release branch.
If you attempt to merge the bugfixes from main to release you probably run into problems, because the bugfixes are entangled with other changes that you don't want in your release branch (possibly because they implement new features for the next release).
Also the merging process might result in new mistakes/errors and break the release which you probably do not want.

See:
[image]

This also depends on the question if you want to alter an existing release at all.
You could instead create a new release based on the previous one and then merge 
the desired changes from main and subsequently fix them.

This is more or less the same, but with the difference that you never touch an existing release (which may be of importance for you or may be not).

See:
[image]

A clean way to update the existing release would be to branch off a temporary branch
from your release branch, then merge the relevant changes from main. After subsequently fixing the temporary branch you can merge it to the release which should now be a simple copy operation without the risk of breaking anything.

See:
[image]

**Update**:
After reading your question again I found that you're thinking about changing in the release and then merging to main.
IMHO a release branch should never ever be used for developing any changes. It should always only pick up changes that were developed and tested in other branches. After all the reason of having release branches is that they are stable and reliable. Any development ruins that.